# Recuperar datos datatables responsive

Tags: jquery, datatables

Estoy usando datatables para mostrar información y la ultima columna tengo un boton con acciones (Editar, eliminar..etc)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En este caso, el boton editar por ejemplo tiene el siguiente codigo:

```
 <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mdlEditPressTask" class="edit">
      <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
      Editar
</a>
```

Tengo:

> var table = $("#tabla-tareas").DataTable({...});

Para recuperar los datos hago lo siguiente:

```
 //EDIT DATA TASK  MODAL
    $("#tabla-tareas tbody").on("click", "a.edit", function () {            
        var data = table.row($(this).parents("tr")).data();


        $("#frmEditPressTask #id_press_task").val(data.id);
        $("#frmEditPressTask #title").val(data.title);
    });
```

Ahora cuando es responsive, no puedo recuperar la información de la fila.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola el problema es al parecer que el DataTable se dibuja de otro modo cuando el ancho de la tabla es mayor que el ancho de la pantalla. En resumen deberías mantener los datos para búsqueda en otro esquema por ejemplo un array en memoria. o buscar de las 2 formas.